# data to read my json file in IONIC

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

This world is sad to cry , am blocked for two hours with a problem that i couldnt define ,i can't retrieve data from my json file ,everything in my code seems correct.

This is my factory:

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('starter.services')


.factory('userService',function ($http) {

 
        
        return{
   
   getUsers:function(){
    return $http.get("http://localhost:26309/api/User/getAll/").then(function (response) {
       return response.data;
                        });
   }
   
  }
  
});
```

and this controller :

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['starter.services'])


 .controller('UsersCtrl', function($scope,userService) {
  $scope.Users = [];
userService.getUsers().then(function (data) { $scope.Users= data.data; }); });
 
 
});
```

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/UserControllerIonic.js"></script>
   <script src="js/UsersServiceIonic.js"></script>
   
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="UsersCtrl">
  <ion-view>
     <div class = "list" >
            <a class = "item" ng-repeat = "user in Users">
                <h2>{{user.nom}}</h2>
               
            </a>
        </div>
</ion-view>
 
 
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance

**SOLUTION**

i solved the problem by :

1- adding in the config.xml the permission `<allow-navigation href="http://*/*"/>`

2-installing cordova-plugin-whitelist `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist`

3-add control-allow-origin extention to chrome :https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related?hl=en-US

and finally : specifying the type of data returned by the back-end controller by adding this code to my **Global.asax** in *Application_start* method :`config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting =
                Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);`

hope this helps someone

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?  It's hard to tell what's going on from this.  Are you getting a response back from the server?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to resolve your `$http` call inside factory.

JS:

```
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, MyService){
  var url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
  MyService.getData(url).then(function(res){
    console.log(res.data);
    $scope.data = res.data;
  });
})
.service('MyService', function($http){
  return {
    getData: function(url){
      return $http.get(url);
    }
  }
})
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in data">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are resolving the promise in service with the value `response.data`, and again expecting the resolved value to have `data` property. Change your service code as below:

```
'use strict';
angular
  .module('starter.services')
  .factory('userService',function ($http) {
    return {        
      getUsers: function(){
        return $http.get("http://localhost:26309/api/User/getAll/").then(function (response) {
          return response;
        });
      }
    }
});
```

Or simply return the promise as below:

```
'use strict';
angular
  .module('starter.services')
  .factory('userService',function ($http) {
    return {        
            getUsers: function(){
                return $http.get("http://localhost:26309/api/User/getAll/");
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: i have this error : Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: responseProvider <- response <- UsersCtrl
l

Comment: Can you provide the complete code? I think your definitions are not correct. It would be good to have them in a plunkr or jsbin

Comment: Please add `app.js`, `UserControllerIonic.js` and `UsersServiceIonic.js` files in the plunkr